# Setting file creation date to January 1, 1976 but nothing is working unless year is after 1980

Tags: c#

The value of strYear is 1976. I setting the creation date to January 1, 1976 but nothing is happening. If the year is 1977, 1978, or 1979 it doesn't work. What could be the cause of this? Do dates starting with the year 1980 only work?

```c#
 //Change File Created Date to Januray 1 and the year of the file already in meta-data
                DateTime datTime = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt16(strYear), 2, 2, 12, 59, 0, 0);
                File.SetCreationTime(files, datTime);
```

Comment: `File.SetCreationTime` is a thin wrapper around the Win32 `SetFileTime` function. It *should* support whatever date the underlying file system supports as it has no limitations itself (NTFS can support file times before 1980, but FAT cannot).

Answer (score 5):

Likely this is coming from the minimum time of the file system which is 1980 for FAT or MS-DOS compatible file systems.

I'm guessing NTFS volumes will support all the way back to 1601. FAT only goes back to 1980.

Comment: Any way around this?

Comment: [FileTimeToDosDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-filetimetodosdatetime) mentions the date limitations.

Comment: @IsiahJones a better question is why you are storing that on a file.

Comment: @IsiahJones what file system type are you writing to? ntfs? fat?

Comment: For classical music files. Want to make the creation date to the year of when the music was composed. It will allow for the files to be sorted by year by creation date.

Comment: Well, unless you only care for music composed after 1600, that's a non-starter. You'll need to record the composition times separately (or simply store them in the file name itself, as `YYYY-MM-DD <name>`).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your file system, you may be stuck.
See [this article](https://superuser.com/questions/796762/what-is-the-range-of-dates-that-windows-explorer-can-display) for details.
NTFS will allow older dates, but older file systems (DOS/FAT) constrain you to 1980 or younger